# Como recuperar as variáveis de GET depois que foi modificada por .htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Eu tenho a seguinte regra no .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^acesso-erro/(.*) proc_error.php?error=$1 [L]
```

Essa regra recupera as variáveis da URL e coloca numa varavel "error".

Como eu posso recuperar essa variável na página **proc_error.php**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderá receber da mesma forma que se resgata no modo POST ou GET.
Ex. $error = $_GET['error'];

Comment: sim [e php. deu certo